# Next.js 13 api request Error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') at eval

Tags: web, post, next.js, request

Im trying to send request to route.ts at /api/register
from client component register.js
although the user is registered on database i keep getting thie error.

my route.ts function:

```
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const json = await request.json();
  ......
 
  userPool.signUp(json.email, json.password, attributeList, null, (err, result) =>  {
    if (result){
      let json_response = {
        status: "200",
        data: result.user,
      };
      return NextResponse.json(json_response)
    }
    if (err) {
      let error_response = {
        status: "fail",
        message: "error",
      };
      return NextResponse.json(error_response)
    }
  });
}
```

my client function:

```
const registerUser = async () => {
    try{
      const response = await fetch("/api/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      switch (response.status) {
        case 200:
          const data = await response.json();
          setMessage("User created successfully");
          setConfirmationActive(true)
          break;
.....
      }
    }catch(e){
      setMessage(e.toString())
    }
  };
```

thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the userPool.signUp callback is asynchronous, the return statements inside it are not affecting the outer POST function's response as might expect.

To resolve this issue, i had to make sure that the response is sent from the outer POST function, after the userPool.signUp callback has completed. You can use async/await to handle the asynchronous behavior more effectively. Here's how i modify your code:

```
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
      userPool.signUp(json.email, json.password, attributeList, null, (err, result) => {
          if (result) {
              let json_response = {
                  status: "200",
                  data: result.user,
              };
              console.log(json_response);
              resolve(NextResponse.json(json_response));
          } else if (err) {
              let error_response = {
                  status: "fail",
                  message: "error",
              };
              resolve(NextResponse.json(error_response));
          }
      });
  });
```